# How to combine criteria in a WHERE clause with AND (POSTGRES)

Tags: sql, postgresql, where-clause, multiple-conditions

I need to meet two criteria to select data from a table then meet a separate third criteria.  The issue I seem to be running into is that I can't seem to "group" (for lack of a better term) the first criteria together before checking the third.

```
select * 
from locations 
where (town <> '2' and name <> 'south park') and report_number = 12345;
```

The town AND name conditions need to be combined as i have a name of "south park" in town #1 as well, and I DO want to pull that record along with everything that is not "south park" in town #2.

I was able to work around it (but very crudely) by doing the following:

```
select * 
from locations 
where (town || name <> '2south park') and report_number = 12345;
```

The first query gets rid of everything in town 2 and all the "south park" names in report 12345

The second works, but I'm hoping that there's a better way of writing this query.

Comment: "grouping" the criteria together doesn't make sense.  All three need to evaluate to true for a row to be returned.

Comment: Trying to find a clean way of treating two of the criteria as a single TRUE, instead of a T/F returning F (which, yes it SHOULD return F).  Trying to find how to make that happen and I think your code below has it.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the logic you want uses `or`, not `and`:

```
where (town <> '2' or name <> 'south park') and 
      report_number = 12345;
```

You might find this simpler to follow as:

```
where not (town = '2' and name = 'south park') and 
      report_number = 12345;
```

Comment: both solutions return duplicates for the records I WANT to get... selecting distinct would alleviate this but still seems kludgey to me (i get 2 sets of town 3 south park)

Comment: @apags . . . Nothing in this `where` clause removes "duplicates".  The intention is to implement the filters in your question.

Comment: you are correct, after tracing things down, the dupes, it looks like, are coming from a join further down the road, so thank you for this.